# Adjust width of some column in Nz-Table dynamic columns

Tags: angular, antd, ng-zorro-antd

I am using Nz-Zorro ie; ng-antd to design table. Here I am dynamically calling the table header.

I have 4 columns and I want reduce the width of 2 columns by its name. How can I do that ?

```
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th *ngFor="let column of listOfColumns">
       {{ column.name }}
     </th>
   </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a `colWidth: "string"` property to each of your `listOfColumns` item's class and change it in your model with your model key. then use `[nzWidth]` to change the column width:

```
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th  *ngFor="let column of listOfColumns" [nzWidth]="column.colWidth">
       {{ column.name }}
     </th>
   </tr>
</thead>
```